# Log4J dynamic configuration

Tags: java, logging, dynamic, log4j

Is there any way to configure log4j loggers dynamically. I want each instance of a class to write to a different file (base on say some property that is unique between instances). I would like to configure everything except the file from XML configuration and then for each instance to set the file.

Is there any way to do this using log4j?

Comment: Not sure i understand, but i think you want to create an Appender for each class you have.  You will have to instantiate the logger in each class with the name of the class.  I hope you dont have too many class in your project cause you will end up with a lot of .log

Comment: I just want this for a class, that will have several instances (lets say up to 10). And each instance will have a unique ID. I want each instance to write to let say the file ID.log

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, from your comment, here what i would try.

I imagine you will create your 10 instances at the start of your app.!?  anyway.

In your log4j.xml, define 10 appender with name = yourUniqueId  (this unique id will be sort of hard coded)

Make these appender write to yourUniqueid.log

```
<logger name="yourUniqueId" additivity="false">
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</logger>

<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
<param name="File" value="/path/yourfile.log"/>

    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Then in your object constructor, instantiate the right Logger with the object unique id.

Something like that:

```
public MyClassContructor(){
     String uniqueId = getMyUniqueIdFromSomewhere();
     logger = Logger.getLogger(uniqueId);
}
```

I think you don't want to mess around with log4j.xml, then you would have to use the log4j API and create your own appender based on your unique id

Something like this:

```
public class YourClass{
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(YourClass.class);
SimpleLayout layout = new SimpleLayout();
FileAppender appender = null;

public YourClass() {
    try {
        appender = new FileAppender(layout, "/path/tolog/yourUniqueId.log", false);
        logger.addAppender(appender);

        logger.setLevel((Level) Level.DEBUG);

    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Printing ERROR Statements",e);
    }
}
```

This way each instance of YourClass would write to a different log file.  all you have to do is think of a way of getting this uniqueId when you call the constructor.

Hope it help.